# Sorting one column based on another one in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

How do I get column E to skip rows where there no duplicate in column A.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to figure out how to insert blank rows in Column `E` and `F` where there is a missing value based on `A`... use a `Vlookup()` in Column `D` to grab the relevant pieces from Column `F`:

Assuming your data starts on `A16` according to your picture, in `D16` enter:

```
=Vlookup(A16, E:F, 2, False)
```

And copy that down. Now you will have Column `F` values in their appropriate rows in Column `D`.

Comment: I uploaded the original spreadsheet, I need to add the values in column H to column I, but I need to match up the cells based on columns A and G.

Comment: So, in a new column you could do `=Vlookup(A267, G:H, 2, FALSE) + Vlookup(A267, G:I, 3, FALSE)` That will look up the value in `A267` into Column `G`, when it finds it's match, it will first grab the value in Column `H` (the second column of Range `G:H`) and then it will add to that the found value in Column `I` (the third column in Range `G:I`). `Vlookup` is your friend for this type of situation where you have to find values in one list, inside another, and then return corresponding values in other columns.

Comment: It tells me the value is not available.

Comment: It will do that if the value in `A` is not found in `G`. You can wrap your `Vlookup` in an `iferror()` formula: `=IFERROR(Vlookup(A267, G:H, 2, FALSE), 0) + IFERROR(Vlookup(A267, G:I, 3, FALSE), 0)` That will set the result of the lookup to `0` in the event that you get a `#N/A` return from `VLOOKUP()`